# Create table canvas with dynamic row and column values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to display the table canvas. here row and column count will come from db like,

Row = 4 and column =4 so canvas/table will be created with row 4 and column 4 so it will create empty table like below where i put 3 td data for testing .

```
3   3   3   3
3   3   3   3
3   3   3   3
3   3   3   3
```

Jquery code is,

```
function createCanvas(rcount,ccount,elementid) {
    var td = {
   'TileHt': 40,
   'TileWd': 40
 };




 mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ class: "basicTable" }).attr({width: rcount*td.TileWd}).attr({height: ccount*td.TileHt}).css('z-index', '-9999');

 


    for (var i = 0; i < rcount; i++) {
    
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(mytable);

    for (var j = 0; j < ccount; j++) {

        

            $('<td>test</td>').css('background-color', "#A3FF47").attr({width: td.TileWd}).attr({height: td.TileHt}).appendTo(row); 
        

      
    }    
  }


  mytable.appendTo("#box").draggable({ cursor: "move", grid: [ 40, 40 ] });
  }
```

But now i have jquery array with data like below,

```
["+12 Years", "art logo", "business", "Choas Symbol", "convergent", "define", 
"discover", "discover symbol", "+12 Years", "art logo", "business", "Choas Symbol", 
"convergent", "define", "discover", "discover symbol"]
```

and i have this data in jquery variable now i want to display these data inside that canvas on each block instead of 3. i am not getting how to use this array inside above for loop code. please help me out. 1st block should have "+12 Year" and second block should have 'art logo" so on.

Comment: `i * 4 + j` is the array index.

Comment: Great it wokred. thank you

Comment: what if we have different number for row and column? for example row: 4 and columns 3. ?

Comment: Formula would be (assuming the for-next-loop): `current-index = row-count * number-of-columns-per-row + column-count`. Have a look at this: `var shortDaysInWeek = 'MonTueWedThuFriSatSun'; /* or read translation from a DB */ var shortDayName = substr((dayInWeekNumber - 1) * 3, 3);`. The same principle, completely different use. Calculate an index into a 2D matrix given a number of rows and columns (in both examples 'starting width index 0'). *Any* 2D matrix will do: hours-in-a-day, days-in-a-month, chessboard, Sudoku, to-do-list, etc.

Comment: Typo in previous comment: read `current-row-counter` and `current-column-counter` for `row-count` and `column-count`. Sorry about that!

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know it is more easier to create canvas in core javascript than jQuery

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).